# Сортировка многоуровнего обьекта

Tags: javascript, сортировка, sortable, underscore.js, lodash

```
{
  obj1: [ {value: 10}, {value: 5}, {value: 20},],
  obj2: [ {value: 10}, {value: 7}, {value: 20},],
  obj3: [ {value: 1}, {value: 8}, {value: 10},]
}
```

Как отсортировать с помощью (underscore или lodash) obj1, obj2, obj2 по самому меньшему значению value в обьектах, массива обьектов, тот obj внутри которого value меньше всего, должен идти на первом месте, то есть в данном примере, должно получится так:

```
  {
  obj3: [ {value: 1}, {value: 8}, {value: 10},] // тут 1 меньше всего
  obj1: [ {value: 10}, {value: 5}, {value: 20},], // тут 5 на второе место
  obj2: [ {value: 10}, {value: 7}, {value: 20},] // тут 7 на третье место     
}
```

Comment: именно так невозможно, объекты невозможно отсортировать. Но можно создать массив с ссылками, которые будут указывать на массивы в объекте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сортировать ключи в объекте бесполезная затея, но если что, вот код

```
_.chain(obj)
    .transform(function(result, val, key) {
        result.push({
            key: key,
            vals: val
        });
    }, [])
    .sortBy(function(item) {
        return _.chain(item.vals)
            .map('value')
            .min()
            .value();
    })
    .transform(function(result, val) {
        result[val.key] = val.vals;
    }, {})
    .value();
```

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/stasovlas/kw3jxxua/2/

результат

```
{"obj3":[{"value":1},{"value":8},{"value":10}],
"obj1":[{"value":10},{"value":5},{"value":20}],
"obj2":[{"value":10},{"value":7},{"value":20}]}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! То есть правильней сделать массив обьектов, и тогда сортировать? В моем случаи название ключа важно т.к. obj1... это название категории, перед тем как сделать эту сортировку, я делаю групировку обьектов по названиям категории

Comment: @VadymPetryshyn правильней будет сделать массив объектов, что то типа такого [{category: 'obj1', values:[{"value":10},{"value":5},{"value":20}] }, {...}, {...}], работать с такими данными будет гораздо проще